# Simple fix for scrolling when custom adapter is changing?

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, android-asynctask

Using my Custom Adapter - I am populating the `listiew` using an `AsyncTask`.  The `doInBackground` updates the ArrayLists which are used for the Custom Adapter.  The `onProgressUpdate` calls the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

When loading a lot of files, I wanted the UI to be responsive, but when you try to scroll when the list is still being populated, I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.


@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {
            //Opens thumbnails for each image contained in the dropbox folder
            try {
                DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];
                numFiles = fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath).size();
                for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {
                    String filename = fileInfo.path.getName();


                    try{
                        if(!fileInfo.isFolder)
                        {
                            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            pix.add(image);
                            paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                            publishProgress(1); //use this to update the ListView
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //must be a folder if it has no thumb, so add folder icon
                            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dbfolder);
                            pix.add(image);
                            paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                            publishProgress(1);


                        }

                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.gc();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } finally {
            }
            return true;
        }

       @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {

           if(pix.size()==1) // //not ideal but works for now, only bind the adapter if its the first time we have looped through.
           {
           adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pix, paths, numFiles);
           lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
           }

           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           lstView.requestLayout();
           super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        }
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here?  And what can I do to prevent it?
I was originally using a progressbar and only displayed the fill contents once they had all loaded, but I would much rather show the incremental load and let the user scroll even as its loading the content.

p.s. I see this is a common enough issue and have read several similar questions, but I still cannot work out what I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter has pix, numFiles and paths as data source and since you are modifying those collections in **doInBackground()** which is running **on a non UI thread** you get this exception.

`new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pix, paths, numFiles);` passes those collection via **reference**.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this - will this mean the list will automatically jump back to the top when the adapter is updated?

Comment: so in my onProgressUpdate I should just have:  adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pix, paths, numFiles);
           lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: No, the problem is that you're adding items to your pix and path collection in a thread. Creating the adapter in onProgressUpdate doesn't change the fact that you are modifying the adapters data from a non UI thread.

You can't do it this way. You should wait until doinBackground is done and fill your adapter in onPostExecute() and than call notifyDatasetChanged(). Thats the way asyncTask is used.

Comment: So I have to wait until the entire AsyncTask has completed before displaying my List?  There is no way to display them one by one as they arrive?  Its better for the user to see the items loading, rather than have a "please wait" dialog for a few seconds.

Comment: There are ways to do this. But AsyncTask is maybe not the best solution for this as onProgressUpdate is not intended to do this.